# How to open volume by name

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, language-agnostic

I need to open volume by name(get volume handle). The target volume name is *"\?\Volume{A25CF44F-8CB3-46E7-B3A7-931385FDF8CB}\"* and this should works. According to [CreateFile function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx)

> You can also open a volume by referring to its volume name.

The C# code:

```
public static class Wrapper
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
     public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string filename,
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAccess access,
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileShare share,
     IntPtr securityAttributes, // optional SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES struct or IntPtr.Zero
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode creationDisposition,
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAttributes flagsAndAttributes,
     IntPtr templateFile);
}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sourceVol = @"\\?\Volume{A25CF44F-8CB3-46E7-B3A7-931385FDF8CB}\";

        SafeFileHandle sourceVolHandle = Wrapper.CreateFile(sourceVol, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (sourceVolHandle.IsInvalid)
            throw new Win32Exception(); //Here I got "The system cannot find the path specified"
```

So how to open volume by name? *(I know that I can open volume using drive letter "\\.\C:" but that is not accepteble)*

Comment: Error checking is wrong. Read the docs. Check the return value to detect error. But the volume name is probably wrong all the same.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks. I have corrected. But problem remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open volume we need to remove trailing slash, so:

```
string sourceVol = @"\\?\Volume{A25CF44F-8CB3-46E7-B3A7-931385FDF8CB}";
```